# Intellij Community Edition stuck with Scala & SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have the following IntelliJ version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3
```

With this, I tried to import a simple Scala / SBT project, but IntelliJ is stuck and says that it is Refreshing my-project sbt project and it just hangs there! Any ideas as to what this problem is all about? Is this something known?

I have installed the Scala plugin v2019.1.7 and SBT plugin v1.8.0

It is really annoying to face this issue! Any clues? What is even more annoying is that when I import this project into IntelliJ, it would just put a lock on the .sbt and .ivy folders! IntelliJ is stuck and becomes unusable and I have to kill it and manually delete those lock files!

EDIT: Here is my build.sbt

```
name := "milo-client-examples"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.milo" % "sdk-client" % "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.eclipse.milo" % "server-examples" % "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

Doing a

> sbt clean compile

from the command like works flawlessly!

Comment: Can you give more info about the project ? Do you have the sbt logs ? Have you tried compiling the project on command line with sbt ?

Comment: There is no single solution for this problem. The best way to solve this is to go to the project directory, delete the .idea folder and import the sbt project again. It works most of the times.

Comment: I have tried it many times, but with no luck!

Comment: Can you share your build.sbt file

Comment: I have added it! Take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a proper answer, but I guess it might help someone stuck with the same issue! doing a

> sbt clean compile

from the command line against the project and getting the build to success and then opening the project in IntelliJ works!